# Bad word list in forum (preg match) only count

Tags: php

in my forum I would like to check a string (post text and post title) for bad words. The words should NOT be replaced. When the FIRST bad word is count, do something. I dont want to work with foreach because foreach will do the echo for every bad word found. I need only a count. If count a bad word then > go

I have already

```
$str = $row['post_text'].$topic_data['topic_title'];
$bad = array('badword','badword2');
if (preg_match($str,$bad)){
echo 'true';
}else{
echo 'false';
}
```

this did not work..thank for help

Comment: what's the meaning behind "did not work" ?

Comment: Be very careful not to make the [clbuttic mistake](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clbuttic).

Comment: preg_match is a regular expression match, your $str is not a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use for each on your bad word array and check it as a stristr() of the $str, on success exit the for each with $badword = true, then you can post a response if $badword == true after the loop.

Comment: Hi Al, this sounds good for me, thats what I want. Would you please give me the code? thank you so much.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php and http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Comment: nice, 2 Links. I like stackoverlflow because I found often copy and paste solutions. When this so easy for you, then please post me a solution... $comment = $row['post_text'].$topic_data['topic_title'];
$fillout = array("badword1","badword2", "badword3");
$clean = true;
  preg_match("/".$fillout."/", $comment, $matches);
  if(count($matches) > 0)
  {
    echo'true';
    $clean = false;
  }

 
if($clean)
{
  // Do insert
}

Comment: $comment = $row['post_text'].$topic_data['topic_title'];
$fillout = array("badword1","badword2", "badword3");
$clean = true;
  preg_match("/".$fillout."/", $comment, $matches);
  if(count($matches) > 0)
  {
    echo'true';
    $clean = false;
  }

 
if($clean)
{
  // Do insert
}

Where do I add there the stristr part